# ellipsis does not work for few words

Tags: css

I have following css for ellipsis. It works for few texts. But for few texts it does not work.

Note - this is for a two line 
Please help

```
.myclass {
    max-width: 210px;
    width: 290px;
    height: 3em;
    min-height: 3em;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;     
}
```

Comment: Can you made snippet ?

Comment: _"It works for few texts. But for few texts it does not work."_ Makes no sense whatsoever

Comment: My text is very long. when it goes to second line ellipsis does not work

Comment: May be you should give this a try... https://codepen.io/martinwolf/pen/qlFdp

Answer (score 3):

Use Following code

```
 <div class="myclass">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and 
   typesetting industry.</div>
<style>
    .myclass {
        max-width: 250px;
        min-height: 3em;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
</style>
```